# rails: command not found ["not in your path"]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash

Working on a brand new ArchLinux install with rails (4) installed using gem. Logged in as usr instead of root, per ArchWiki recommendation for using gem.

Install is successful, but puts out this warning:

```
WARNING:  You don't have /home/[usr]/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin in your PATH,
      gem executables will not run.
```

After much googling, I edited both .bashrc and .bash_profile hoping to rectify the issue.

```
#
# ~/.bashrc
#

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return

alias ls='ls --color=auto'
PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '

export GEM_HOME=~/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
export PATH=$PATH:/home/[name]/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin

$(ruby -rubygems -e "puts Gem.user_dir")/bin

#
# ~/.bash_profile
#

[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc

export GEM_HOME=~/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
export PATH=$PATH:/home/[usr]/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin

$(ruby -rubygems -e "puts Gem.user_dir")/bin
```

I know it's redundant, but I've seen recommendations for both files, and after one didn't work I was hoping the other would.

Either way, even after uninstalling and reinstalling rails, the warning still pops up and rails is still not a usable command. I'm not really sure where to go from here, since it seems those lines tend to fix it for others.

Comment: export PATH=$PATH:$GEM_HOME/bin The [name] and [ edit] placeholder in your path is wrong. Ensure: your paths are right: `source ~/.bashrc && ls $GEM_HOME`

Comment: You'd better use RVM.

Comment: RVM is giving me a whole host of new problems, including telling me to remove GEM HOME because it's in conflict, and the rails command is STILL not found.

Comment: I uninstalled RVM and put the line from @jgb back in, and now the rails server is starting. Perhaps if I have more issues down the line I'll try RVM again. Thank you both very much for your help.